# Uncaught referenceError: newMoney is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Why is it not defined though i already defined newMoney at the top here is my code :

```
             var deduct = 100;
             var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;
             var username = getUserName(); //get the current user
              // send a message to the server that the e-money value has changed
             socket.emit('update e-money', username, newMoney);

             console.log("Emitting the data to the server side - emoney: " + newMoney + " with the name money of : " + username);
            //end 

            clearTimeout(interval);
            //send the data to the server
            socket.emit('chat message', getUser());
            var interval = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.'+getUser()).fadeIn();
            },5000);
        });

             socket.on('update e-money response', function (data) {
             alert("Your money is: "+ data.newMoney);
             console.log("Your money is: "+ data.newMoney);
             });
```

and on my server side here is my code :

```
 //emoney
socket.on('update e-money', function (data) {
 var userName = data.username;
 var newMoney = data.newMoney;
//var query = {"name": userName};

  // update the entry on the database
  User.findOneAndUpdate({"username":userName}, {"$set":{"e_money": "300" }}, { upsert: true, returnOriginal:false }, function (err, doc) {

if (err) {
  console.log("There was an error: " + err);
  console.log(userName);
  io.emit('update e-money error', { error: err });

} else {

    io.emit('update e-money response', { newMoney: newMoney });
    console.log(newMoney);
}
  });
  });
```

I dnt know why it is undefined . Can you help me guys . Anyone.

Comment: so you're saying sir i should do it like this `{newMoney: data,newMoney}`

Comment: ahm i'm clearly sure i guess cause im putting it if there's no error this one will execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
  var deduct = 100;
  var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;
  var username = getUserName(); //get the current user
   // send a message to the server that the e-money value has changed
  socket.emit('update e-money', username, newMoney);
```

i should have done it like this

```
  var deduct = 100;
  var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;
  var username = getUserName();
  var compile = {newMoney, username};
```

then use it on my server side :)

then i'll emit it like this

```
 socket.emit('update e-money', compile);
```